# How to increment a JavaScript variable using a button press event

Tags: javascript

Can I create a javascript variable and increment that variable when I press a button (not submit the form).
Thanks!

Comment: This question should have a title like "how to increment a JavaScript variable based on a web page button press event".

Comment: @Parappa you should have edited it then

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
</script>
```

and

```
<button onclick="counter++">Increment</button>
```

Comment: I was typing it, when you posted it.

Comment: You had an open input tag and a close button tag.

Answer (score 10):

The purist way to do this would be to add event handlers to the button, instead of mixing behavior with the content (LSM, Layered Semantic Markup)

```
<input type="button" value="Increment" id="increment"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    // JQuery way
    $('#increment').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        count++;
    });
    // YUI way
    YAHOO.util.Event.on('increment', 'click', function (e) {
        YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
        count++;
    });
    // Simple way
    document.getElementById('increment').onclick = function (e) {
        count++;
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        e.returnValue = false;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: There's no default action for a button so you don't need to prevent it.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;

function increase()
{
    i++;
    return false;
}</script><input type="button" onclick="increase();">
```

Comment: oh sure, go with the nice function call. :)

Comment: with "return false" stated in the function or in the onclick event, it will not post the form.

Comment: Would it post the form being a button and not a submit?

Comment: A `button` does not submit a form. A `submit` does.

Comment: Also, for the `return false` in the function to have any effect, you need to do `onclick="return increase();"`.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to see the results of this script and was able to do so by incorporating the below:

```
var i=0;

function increase()
{
i++;
document.getElementById('boldstuff').innerHTML= +i;
}

<p>var = <b id="boldstuff">0</b></p>
<input type="button" onclick="increase();">
```

add the "script" tag above all and a closing script tag below the function end curly brace. Returning false caused firefox to hang when I tried it. All other solutions didn't show the result of the increment, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type = "button"` instead of `"submit"`, then add an `onClick` handler for it.

For example:

```
<input type="button" value="Increment" onClick="myVar++;" />
```

Comment: @rgz nice tag. Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
<head>
<script type='javascript'>
var x = 0;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='button' onclick='x++;'/>
</body>
```

[Psuedo code, god I hope this is right.]

Answer (score 0):

yes, supposing your variable is in the global namespace:

```
<button onclick="myVar += 1;alert('myVar now equals ' + myVar)">Increment!!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something similar to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count;
function increment(){
    count++;
}
</script>

...
```

and

```
<input type="button" onClick="increment()" value="Increment"/>
```

or

```
<input type="button" onClick="count++" value="Increment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem.  Needed to append as many text inputs as the user wanted, to a form.  The functionality of it using jQuery was the answer to the question:

```
<div id='inputdiv'>
<button id='mybutton'>add an input</button>
</div>

<script>
var thecounter=0; //declare and initialize the counter outside of the function
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(){
thecounter++;
$('#inputdiv').append('<input id="input'+thecounter+'" type="text/>);
});
</script>
```

Adding the count to each new input id resulted in unique ids which lets you get all the values using the jQuery serialize() function.