# Counter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, counter

On a website the user should click a **button**.
By the `onclick()` event a counter should count up.

I want to use JavaScript to count up, but how can I save the result?

Comment: save, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Try using cookies to save the result as a tiny text file on the user's computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment a JavaScript variable using a button press event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837648/how-to-increment-a-javascript-variable-using-a-button-press-event)

Comment: If you want to save the clicks of all the users you must have server side script like PHP .Net Ruby etc.

Comment: What exactly you want to count?

Comment: you need count++; store it in database :)

Comment: `localStorage` is quite well sported now - screw *IE7*. [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3hHH/).

Answer (score 1):

You must have a server which holds the counter. Each time that button gets clicked, the incremented counter  should be updated on your server database through some ajax like request.

On the client, you have `html5` `local storage` but it will not be available always because that is in the client's decision.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs entirely client side, so unless you're planning on posting the data to a handler file, you can't really "save" the data.

All you can do is store the data inside a cookie, using jQuery.cookie library (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) or something similar. But remember that this will only save one users particular instance of the click recording, and not every single users experience.

If you're using jQuery (which makes this process much easier)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var clickCounter = 0;
   $("#yourdiv").on("click", function() {
       clickCounter++;
   });
});
```

To display the counter on the website, you would then need:

```
<span id="clickCount"></span>
```

And a little more jQuery

```
$("#clickCount").text(clickCounter);
```