# Increment number on key press (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am trying to display a paragraph tag on the screen using html. I want to then be able to press a key and have the number in that paragraph tag increase. That is all that I want to do.

This seems like it should be easy to do but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: [`node.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: from Stackoverflow:[How to increment a JavaScript variable using a button press event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837648/how-to-increment-a-javascript-variable-using-a-button-press-event) and from Stackoverflow:[Javascript Get Element by Id and set the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649173/javascript-get-element-by-id-and-set-the-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. This is without jQuery, but it's what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/2rAj9/

The JS:

```
var p = document.querySelector('p')

document.addEventListener('keydown', increment, false);

function increment() {
    var number = parseInt(p.innerText);
    number++;
    p.innerText = number;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<p class="increment">0</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').keydown(function(){
        console.log('keydown');
        $('#increment').text(parseInt($('#increment').text())+1);   
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="increment">0</p>
```

Comment: Now can I get a certain key and when I press that key it increments?