# Start at 0 and keep adding by 10

Tags: javascript

This script is designed when you press the button it will show 0 and when you press the button again it will show 10 and keep adding by 10 every time you press the

button for example 0,10,20,30,40,etc... how can I do this I tried many methods but I can not generate something like this.

```js
document.querySelector('#add-by-ten').addEventListener('click',addByTen);

function addByTen(){
/*???*/
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = ?;
}
```

```html
<button id='add-by-ten'>Add by ten</button>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment a JavaScript variable using a button press event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837648/how-to-increment-a-javascript-variable-using-a-button-press-event)

Comment: try to search similar problems before positing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resultElement = document.getElementById('result')

function addByTen(){
   var value = parseInt(resultElement.innerHTML, 10);

   if (!Number.isInteger(value)) {
      resultElement.innerHTML = 0;
   } else {
      resultElement.innerHTML = value + 10;
   }
}

document.querySelector('#add-by-ten').addEventListener('click',addByTen);
```

Comment: O my god!!! :-O....... @Abdulfatai you are my new hero ha ha ha thank you very much Abdulfatia that's what I was looking for thank you.

Comment: Hey abdulfatia the code did not work in Internet Explorer I updated the code so it should now work in IE now. I'm just letting you know.

Comment: and I need your approval so my edit on your code answer will show publicly.

Comment: Thats awsome @fsofb. However, about approval of your edit, how will I do that? haven't done that before here.

Answer (score 1):

using a `var counter = 0;` in the outer scope, then add 10 when you click the button.

```js
document.querySelector('#add-by-ten').addEventListener('click',addByTen);
var counter = 0;

window.onload  = function init(){
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = counter;
}
function addByTen(){
   counter+=10;
   document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = counter;
}
```

```html
<button id='add-by-ten'>Add by ten</button>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but how can I get the first click to at 0?

Comment: @DannyLee simplest way give the div `0` value, or my answer use `window.onload` event filled the value to div

Comment: Thats what the second line in the function does, when no value has been set on first click, it is set to zero

Comment: @D-Shih How can I do this without the 0 showing on page load I want to press the button the first time and it will show 0 and then when I press the button the second time it will show 10 and if I press it again it will show 20 etc.. you know by every button press

Comment: @DannyLee Are yo using two SO accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable, let number = 0;

Set inner.Text to that variable.

Then have your plusTen function () {number = number +10}

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it!

There's four steps to achieving this:

1. Use your quest selector to retrieve the current value from your label.
2. Cast the retrieved `innerHTML` as a number.
3. Increment this number by 10.
4. Set your new number as the `innerHTML` of your query selector.

---

Here's a working copy of the code:

```js
document.querySelector('#add-by-ten').addEventListener('click',addByTen);

function addByTen(){
  var currentValue = document.querySelector('#result');
  currentValue.innerHTML = Number(currentValue.innerHTML) + 10;
}
```

```html
<button id='add-by-ten'>Add by ten</button>
<p id='result'>0</p>
```

> There are a few ways to achieve what you're doing, which could involve storing a global variable to keep your count; or by using DOM manipulation like your original attempt.